# Running Android on Mips Architecture

Tags: android, port, mips

If I have a set top box(Mips arch) with the source code(with a modified Linux kernel) which makes it run, and now I want to run Android on it, how do I proceed? Updating my kernel source by comparing it with the common Android kernel tree should be a good start right?
I also want to know what libraries are made use of by the Android run time. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

[MIPS Android web site](http://www.mipsandroid.org/) has Android source code which has already been ported and optimized for MIPS architecture. Once you have MIPS version of the Android source code, you can follow the standard [Android porting guide](http://source.android.com/porting/index.html).

Comment: I downloaded the generic sources from mipsandroid website. But it uses a prebuilt kernel. I have my own kernel source which I've modified to accommodate android kernel level changes. How do I proceed with porting?